# Detect if browser supports google graphs

Tags: javascript, html, browser, graph

Yesterday I was having an issue with some google graphs on my site while running opera. I was getting the error "your browser does not support graphs". Today Its absolutely fine and in fact seems to be running a bit quicker.

I'd like to have a backup in my javascript so that if its not supported Ill just display a table.

Is there any such way to do this or do i need to check against a list of incoming browsers and figure it out for myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/interactive/docs/:

> Charts are rendered using HTML5/SVG technology to provide
>   cross-browser compatibility (including VML for older IE versions) and
>   cross platform portability to iPhones, iPads and Android.

They are apparently using inline SVG. http://caniuse.com/#search=inline%20svg isn't very useful here because that's about HTML5 parser recognizing SVG content, Google is generating SVG content dynamically however. I think that the following code snippet tests for inline SVG support correctly:

```
var svgRoot = null;
if ("createElementNS" in document)
  svgRoot = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
if (svgRoot && "width" in svgRoot)
  alert("Inline SVG supported");
```

If a dynamically created SVG element has SVG-specific properties then everything should be fine. You will still have to assume that MSIE is generally supported (via VML). Or use [How do you detect support for VML or SVG in a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654112/how-do-you-detect-support-for-vml-or-svg-in-a-browser/654516#654516) to detect VML support. And that will hopefully match the compatibility checks that Google is performing (minus glitches like the one you apparently observed).

Comment: If using Modernizr you could also check for inline svg support like so: `if (Modernizr.inlinesvg) { // supports inline svg }`