# explain javascript function for detecting vml

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, vml

This is a function used to detect VML support in browsers. It's part of an html component file for giving border-radius and drop-shadow functionality to older versions of IE. I would like this explained to me, the step-by-step logic of it:

```
function supportsVml() {
    if (typeof supportsVml.supported == "undefined"){
        var a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        a.innerHTML = '<v:shape id="vml_flag1" adj="1" />';
        var b = a.firstChild;
        b.style.behavior = "url(#default#VML)";
        supportsVml.supported = b ? typeof b.adj == "object": true;
        a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
    }

    return supportsVml.supported
}
```

Where I am confused:

1. What is supporstVml.supported? Is this a variable, I don't see it declared anywhere else int he file...
2. what is the url(#default#VML) behavior?
3. supportsVml.supported is reassigned a new value based on the conditional, but I have no idea what or why...

Thanks!

Comment: That's some not-so-good code there, whatever it does. Where did it come from?

Comment: @Pointy All over the place lol, http://tobymackenzie.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/css-ie-shadows-and-rounded-corners/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654112/how-do-you-detect-support-for-vml-or-svg-in-a-browser This is code I have to work around, not change. So I'm not interested in optimizing it or changing it, just understanding it. Thanks again!

Comment: Well it's bad because it just is.  That "b" variable is assigned and its value is assumed to be non-null **before** the test is made in the subsequent line. That is, if `a.firstChild` is null, then the assignment to `b.style.behavior` will throw an exception. If it's not `null` then the test made for the `? :` expression is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`supportsVml.supported` is a property of the function, which is used just as a caching for the result.

If it is `undefined` (before the first call), the detection algorithm is run. Afterwards just the cached value is used and the detection is omitted.

The actual detection algorithm tries to add a default VML element and checks, whether this is inserted correctly. If so, VML is supported.

**EDIT**

The `behavior` can attach scripts to the CSS of an element ([link](http://www.css3.com/css-behavior/)). As far as I know, this is unique to older IE versions.

```
supportsVml.supported = b ? typeof b.adj == "object": true;
```

This line uses a ternary operator. It could be rewritten as follows:

```
if ( b ) {
  if ( b.adj == 'object' ) {
    supportsVml.supported = true;
  } else { 
    supportsVml.supported = false;
  }
} else {
  supportsVml.supported = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my first question! Can you tell me what role the behavior plays? Or the conditional statement? I get the VML insert, but these other two are new to me.