# svg if statement

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement, svg

Is there a way that I can check to see if the browser has an SVG viewer?

I want to say something like: if (browser has SVG viewer){//do stuff}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you detect support for VML or SVG in a browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654112/how-do-you-detect-support-for-vml-or-svg-in-a-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how [raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) [detects SVG](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.core.js#L323):

```
if (window.SVGAngle || document.implementation.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#BasicStructure", "1.1")) {
    alert('supports SVG');
}
```

Comment: This was most helpful. I didn't even know about raphael.js until just now. Is this if statement only usable with the raphael.js library?

Comment: No it can be used by itself too, which is I think what you wanted.  I was just citing my source for the code.